# Recreate Text effect through HTML5 and Google Text API

Tags: html, text, css, google-api

How can I recreate the text effect in the image below, including shadows and borders using HTML5, CSS3, and Google Text API (if needed)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to recreate the graphic. You could absolutely position the elements, or you could let the elements flow into place nicely.

For the latter, which I prefer, you need a container for the image (as background), a container to hold the text (which will have a semi-transparent background) and then the text itself, broken up into inline/inline-block elements so you can style each.

Here's how I would do it using inline-block to layout the text appropriately and changing the fonts/font-sizes/padding for each text element (including google text API):

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/v6h2g/

*Obviously, I didn't try to mach the font itself.*

Comment: Thanks for the extremely quick reply. It's amazing how you were able to match it so closely.